# Oracle Analytics Date Range

Tags: oracle

While researching Oracle Analytics, I came across this query:

```
select an_id, 
    a_date, 
    min(a_date) over (
        partition by an_id, trunc(a_date) 
        order by a_date
        range between (2.5/24) preceding and (2.5/24) following
    ) mn,
    max(a_date) over (
        partition by an_id, trunc(a_date) 
        order by a_date
        range between (2.5/24) preceding and (2.5/24) following
    ) mx
from a_table
```

I believe this finds the min and max dates for a given `an_id` and `a_date` within a 2.5 hour period.

My question is why does this comparison between `a_date` (a date) and `2.5/24` (a number) work and how can it be modified for ranges of days, months, or years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date type allows arithmetic where a unit of 1 is a day, so SYSDATE + 1 is tomorrow.

For example, try select to_char(sysdate + 1/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MM:SS') from dual -> 1 hour from now.

Comment: HH:MM:SS =  hours, months, seconds... You meant HH:MI:SS

Answer (score 2):

Here are the docs that talk about that specific analytic construct to give some foundational info and add to what jwilson mentioned.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i97640

Answer (score 2):

It's probably clearer to use intervals to specify window ranges:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306%5F01/server.102/b14200/functions104.htm#i89943

```
SELECT last_name,
       hire_date,
       salary,
       SUM(salary) OVER (ORDER BY hire_date 
                         RANGE    NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'year') PRECEDING) AS t_sal 
FROM   employees;
```